# IF/ELSE statement inside PHP variable string

Tags: php, html, if-statement

What is the correct way to use an IF/ELSE statement inside of a variable string?

Example:

```
$htmlOutput = 'The current color of the sky is ' . 
if ($time==="day") { . 'blue.' . } 
else if ($time==="night") { . 'black' . };
```

Obviously that example does not work, but you see what I'm trying to do.  I know I could just continue the variable inside of the if statement like:

```
$htmlOutput .= '';
```

but I'm curious if there's a way to do it as stated above.

Comment: Yep, with a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: Avoid temptations to do anything more complex than a single `if x then y else z` in a ternary operation though. They can be nested but it quickly becomes very unreadable.  `(if x then (if a then b else c) else z)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a `ternary operator` like this

```
$htmlOutput = 'The current color of the sky is ' . ($time == 'day' ? 'blue' : 'black');
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks!  And thanks to all who answered so fast.

Answer (score 2):

use ternary operator instead of if else

```
 $htmlOutput = 'The current color of the sky is ' . ($time==="day") ?'blue':($time==="night")?'black':'';
```

or more simpler is to

```
   $htmlOutput = 'The current color of the sky is ' . ($time==="day") ?'blue':'black';
```

Comment: The first one looks funky. It's either got an extra `?` or a missing `:`.

Comment: it is used for else if , multiple operational statement

Comment: Yes, but it is not valid syntax. Second one looks good though.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
<?php


    $time = "night";

    $htmlOutput = 'The current color of the sky is ' . ($time === 'day' ? 'blue' : 'black');

    echo $htmlOutput;


?>
```